# How to get anchors working in google site HTML

Tags: google-sites

I try to get HTML anchors working on a google site of mine but it blows my head:

- I can get HTML + CSS (plus JS) working with an HTMLBox gadget **BUT** if I have anchors on my code, the gadget rewrite stuff and anchors just no longer works.
- I can get HTML anchors working (by editing page's HTML code directly) **BUT** I cannot keep classes, id and CSS definition (not inline) as google forbid it (and clean it up).

Is there any solutions to that ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about anchor  tags?

Google Sites' regular HTML editor does strip out CSS classes and JS. If you are trying to use anchors with IDs and Class names with rules built into CSS rules, then it won't work - everything has to be inline.

As for the HTML Box, I don't know what your code looks like to comment. If you are trying to use anchor tags to jump to text on the page it won't work because tag ids will get stripped and characters are randomized in HTML Box.

I know of no other alternative except to put the HTML in the regular text editor box, use inline CSS, and then insert a Table of Contents widget from the menu. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about anchor tags.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution: not using google site but embed (via an iframe, yeah!) the page where I need crazy things like CSS and anchors.